# Is Diffie-Hellman key exchange supported in UWP through a free/open source C# package?

Tags: c#, cryptography, uwp

Simple as the title, I was not able to find a documentation/example/package that clearly states the support for UWP.

System.Security.Cryptography namespace has all the support but seems that Windows.Security.Cryptogtraphy does not.

Any suggestions except for paying a licence ? I need this for a college work and not for a professional use.

Thanks

Comment: Just a quick search: https://www.example-code.com/csharp_winrt/dh_key_exchange.asp which might help you.

Comment: Thanks but that's exactly the example I've found. Chilkat DH implementation is not free, and the price is too high for an academic proof of concept.